# Etymology of "norton"?

Tags: etymology, slang

The conversation took a turn towards Monty Python yesterday, and in particular the *Life of Brian*. This film featured as a character (Brian's putative father) the Roman soldier *Nortonus Maximus*, a name derived from *norton*, a slang word for penis.

I was naturally curious as to how a penis could come to be called a *norton*, but when I went to look it up I was surprised to find the word doesn't appear in Farmer & Henley, nor in Partridge, nor in Green. It isn't even in Urban Dictionary, and I can't find this definition anywhere online. But I can distinctly remember using the word before the *Life of Brian* was released, and the scriptwriter clearly expected the joke to be understood by the audience.

So, does anyone know the etymology of this word? And does anyone know why it seems to have been overlooked in the standard references?

Comment: I have never heard ‘norton’ used as a slang term for a penis, but I would assume that (just like ‘dick’, ‘jackson’, ‘willy’, etc.), it is simply a synecdochical use of a male name. This is rather a common way to create slang terms for the member in question in English.

Comment: I've not heard of *jackson* or *norton* in that sense, and neither has OED, which does have relevant entries for *dick, willy* and *peter.*

Comment: The OED also reports "John Thomas" as slang for penis.

Comment: I suppose it might be rhyming slang for something. One name in Britain for a penis is 'Hampton'. There is a place on the Thames called Hampton Wick, so 'Hampton' is rhyming slang for 'dick' or 'prick'. 'Norton' sounds to me as though it could be something like that. But the only place names starting Norton in the UK are 'Norton Canes' and 'Norton Fitzwarren' so I'm no further forward, I'm afraid.

Comment: @WS2, I had thought about that, but I forgot to check. My road atlas has a number of other places starting with _Norton_ but none of them look promising for rhyming slang.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based upon a mis-hearing / an error.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, admittedly, but this does clarify part of what you were asking.

The character's name in Life of Brian is Nortius Maximus or 'Naughtius Maximus'.

A T.V. Tropes disussion on the [Punny Names in Life of Brian](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PunnyName) yields the following:

> Monty Python's Life of Brian. Brian's Roman father was supposedly named Nortius Maximus (which sounds like "Naughtius Maximus"), and Pilate's friend is named Biggus Dickus (with a wife named Incontinentia Buttocks). Brian's first name is not a pun, but it satirizes the trend among Jewish-American families to give their sons old-fashioned English first names such as Irving, Sherman, and George in order to "fit in". (Many of these names almost immediately became stereotyped as "Jewish names".)

This reminds me very much of the quote from the Life of Brian:

> He's not the messiah, he's a very naughty boy!

This is probably why you couldn't find it!

Other than this, I've never heard of using norton as a slang for penis.
Do you have any additional examples of this?

Comment: There was a manager in an establishment I had perhaps better not name, whose surname was _Norton_, and was described as "Norton by name, norton by nature". But that may have been me doing the describing.

Comment: I would have understood that to be a play on "naughty by nature". Being "naughty" may well involve the appendage in question, but that doesn't mean that *norton* is a direct slang term for it.

Answer (score 0):

The only history of Norton being used as (London) slang, as far as I'm aware, is in short for the word 'cold', as in "It's Norton & Gold out here!", where Norton culturally refers to an Australian gold field.

'Taters in the Mould' is of course another London slang term meaning exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

> This film featured as a character (Brian's putative father) the Roman soldier Nortonus Maximus, a name derived from norton, a slang word for penis.

This is simply wrong. It is not Nortonus - it is **Nortius**

From the script (and from the film) http://montypython.50webs.com/scripts/Life_of_Brian/7.htm

> BRIAN: You mean... you were raped?
>
> MANDY: Well, at first, yes.
>
> BRIAN: Who was it?
>
> MANDY: Heh. **Nortius** Maximus his name was. Hmm. Promised me the known world he did. I was to be taken to Rome, House by the Forum. Slaves. Asses' milk. As much gold as I could eat. Then, he, having his way with me had... voom! Like a rat out of an aqueduct.
>
> BRIAN: The bastard!
>
> MANDY: Yeah. So, next time you go on about the 'bloody Romans', don't forget you're one of them.

"**Nortius**" is simply "naughty" with a Latin suffix "-us"

I am voting to close this question as it is based on a listening error.

As a rider, "Norton" appears in a few ribald limericks:

> A lad from Chipping Norton /'s tool was a terribly short 'un / To make up for this lack,/ He had a full sack / and a stroke like a 650 Norton.

See https://www.talkphotography.co.uk/threads/the-tp-limerick-thread.518622/page-2

650 Norton refers to the iconic motorbike, the Norton Dominator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_650_Dominator

and "Stroke" = the displacement of a piston. (MW -> stroke, noun, 2: a single unbroken movement; especially: one of a series of repeated or to-and-fro movements)

Comment: Your limerick would be improved if the first lines were "There once was a lad from Old Porton/Whose tool..." or maybe "near Laughton" — the village in Sussex which is pronounced that way, unlike Loughton, which isn't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I cannot claim the poem as mine but, I resisted the urge to change the words as great quotes :) should never be altered. Edward Lear: There was a Young Person of **Smyrna** / Whose grandmother threatened to burn her. / But she seized on the cat, / and said 'Granny, burn that! / You incongruous old woman of **Smyrna**!'

Comment: Yes, Lear's limericks often repeated words like that. My principal shudder over the Chipping Norton one was that the first line doesn't scan at all and the second only by actually pronouncing *'s.*

Comment: I often think that Lear had only a vague grasp of limericks. Not the best limerick, I agree, but the only one I remember that has "Norton" in it.